# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken-b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net

This is the exception it throws after running an ordinary C# program that prints to console:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime,
Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken-b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system 
cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm using MS Visual Studio with .NET 6.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provided almost no information

- Do you link some libraries
- What is ordinary C# program? (console?)
- Try create new project and compare both versions

This error is almost in 99% cases caused by missing some dll.
Double check your output `bin` directory, and compare with your references.

Tip: maybe wrong .net versions

Comment: Thank you, I created a new project with the solution in the same directory and that one worked